# Spring Social Google - YouTube API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, youtube-api, spring-social

Is there any way how I could upload video on youtube using Spring Social ? How should I go about integrating YouTube Data Api with Spring Social ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google access token can be retrieved using [OAuth 2.0 with the Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)

Regarding video upload you can refer to the official YouTube samples GitHub repository: [UploadVideo.java](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java)

Comment: I have a problem with a Credentials object. I can get an AccessToken from the Spring Social Google but don't know how to pass it to the YouTube data. If I did it as is in example, it would not be integration with spring social.

Comment: If you have an access token you can create a Credential object: `new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken)` and then pass it to [`YouTube.Builder`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java#L76)